# What's wrong this T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is this throwing an error on the equal sign?

```
select IIF((SUBSTRING('A1234', 1, 1) = 'A'), TRUE, FALSE) as IsAustraliaUser
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: There aren't any `TRUE` or `FALSE` literals in SQL Server, but not sure why it's highlighting the `=`. It doesn't for me on SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3128)

Comment: Do this instead: `select IIF((SUBSTRING('A1234', 1, 1) = 'A'), 1, 0) as IsAustraliaUser`

Comment: Just remembered, `IIF` is new for SQL Server 2012. If you run on an earlier version, you'll get the error indicated in the question.

Comment: This question doesn't demonstrate any basic research - such as finding the documentation on [IIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) and checking the version of the server that the OP is working against.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's been awhile since I wrote T-SQL. Many languages can translate TRUE/False to bit. I did look around, and couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I don't understand why people have to be nasty. If you don't like the question, don't answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IIF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is a SQL Server 2012 feature, you'll need to use [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING('A1234', 1, 1)
       WHEN 'A' THEN 'TRUE'
       ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, that did it. Thanks to those below as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace IIF with CASE, also TRUE and FALSE don't exists in SQL Server, you can use VARCHAR or BIT

```
select CASE WHEN SUBSTRING('A1234', 1, 1) = 'A' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as IsAustraliaUser
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, just checked, it's only valid in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SQL supports this syntax of IIF (unless you're using 2012), replace with case.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ( SUBSTRING('A1234', 1, 1) = 'A' ) THEN 'TRUE'
             ELSE 'FALSE'
        END AS IsAustraliaUser
```